# tcpdump: server client communication

Tags: client-server, tcpdump, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I'm capturing the communication between a server and a client with `tcpdump -X`. I noticed a pattern and I'm not sure I fully understand it. In the following I have replaced all the header data (IP and TCP, both 20 bytes, thus **the payload starts on the third row and fifth hex in every packet**) with an X and accordingly all the ascii with dots. But you can read the payload which my question will be referring to.

Below you see the exact pattern that happens every ~15 seconds between the server and the client. If you convert "0500 0000 0000" (**payload of first packet**) from hex to binary to decimal and look that up in an ascii table you will notice that the first message that the client is sending to the server is "ENQ". Then the server responds with "06". Again if you convert that 06 (hex > binary > ascii table) you notice that the server actually says "ACK". In the third packet the client sends zeros (why???). After that there's silence and after 15 seconds this exact pattern repeats itself.

**So here are my questions**:
Is this a known pattern and what is it good for? Must be some sort of "hey, you still there buddy?" communication (please confirm if true?). I'm quite new to exploring network communication. But why does the ENQ come with trailing zeros (first packet)? I mean the ACK (second packet) only comes in with 1 byte which is sufficient and makes sense. I would expect the same for the ENQ? And why does the client send zeros in the third packet before the pattern repeats itself? What's the purpose of that?

```
10:22:10.579188 IP CLIENT > SERVER
        0x0000:  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  ................
        0x0010:  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  ................
        0x0020:  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX 0500 0000 0000       ..............
10:22:10.579360 SERVER > CLIENT
        0x0000:  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  ................
        0x0010:  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  ................
        0x0020:  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX 06                   .........
10:22:10.779322 CLIENT > SERVER
        0x0000:  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  ................
        0x0010:  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  ................
        0x0020:  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX 0000 0000 0000       ..............
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
Looks like keep-alive messages (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-101), but normally it's ACK packets with no data or one octet garbage data. Yours packet are filled with XX so I'm not sure if it's a ACK packets, but only one packet is with one octet (probably) garbage data. Could you show your flag bytes in packets (byte number 34)?

BTW, IMHO there is no packets named ENQ - writing ENQ do you mean flag or something else?

Previous answer:
IP and TCP headers indeed has 20 bytes (usually), but don't forget about first 14 bytes - it is Ethernet header. So, usually valid TCP/IP header is 14 + 20 + 20 = 54 bytes - your packets has 46 or 41 bytes. It's not a TCP packets. May be this article will be helpful: 
    https://www.pacificsimplicity.ca/blog/reading-packet-hex-dumps-manually-no-wireshark

Check Ethernet header to be sure what kind of protocol is used (bytes 13-14 and compare to http://standards-oui.ieee.org/ethertype/eth.txt).

Comment: hi serhiy, thanks for the hint but in this case it's really only the IP and TCP header. the "tcpdump -X" command does that. And I've also verified that there's no optional header data. It's the usual 20 bytes / 5 words. So the payload really starts at hex number 21, which is row 3 / 5th column.

Comment: I just saw your edits: I have put those X'es, you know that right? Regarding the ENQ, as I said: you will find the ENQ in an ascii table which covers all printable and non-printable character. ENQ is the playload of the first packet! 0500 0000 0000 !